# netlify build command failed (create react app)-locally deployed ok

Tags: netlify

I can't figure out why I can deploy perfectly locally but not working when I manually dropped the build folder online or add my repo with Github method. I got the error like below:

> 10:21:21 PM: Build ready to start 10:21:22 PM: build-image version:
> d84c79427e8f83c1ba17bcdd7b3fe38059376b68 10:21:22 PM: build-image tag:
> v3.6.1 10:21:22 PM: buildbot version:
> 44655717ddf0e7bd7f856f5b1154254de54b1d80 10:21:23 PM: Building without
> cache 10:21:23 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build 10:21:23 PM:
> No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo 10:21:23 PM: git
> clone https://github.com/celinevalentine/Games 10:21:24 PM: Preparing
> Git Reference refs/heads/celinev 10:21:26 PM: Different publish path
> detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration
> file: 'build' versus 'build/' in the Netlify UI 10:21:26 PM: Starting
> build script 10:21:26 PM: Installing dependencies 10:21:26 PM: Python
> version set to 2.7 10:21:27 PM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
> 10:21:28 PM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4) 10:21:28 PM:
> Started restoring cached build plugins 10:21:28 PM: Finished restoring
> cached build plugins 10:21:28 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read
> from environment 10:21:29 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1 10:21:29 PM:
> Using PHP version 5.6 10:21:29 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
> 10:21:29 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache 10:21:29 PM: go
> version go1.14.4 linux/amd64 10:21:29 PM: go version go1.14.4
> linux/amd64 10:21:29 PM: Installing missing commands 10:21:29 PM:
> Verify run directory 10:21:31 PM: ​ 10:21:31 PM:
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 10:21:31 PM:   Netlify Build
> 10:21:31 PM:
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 10:21:31 PM: ​ 10:21:31 PM: ❯ Version 10:21:31 PM:   @netlify/build
> 8.3.0 10:21:31 PM: ​ 10:21:31 PM: ❯ Flags 10:21:31 PM:   deployId: 6014fae1970bcf9dcb4a28eb 10:21:31 PM:   mode: buildbot 10:21:31 PM: ​
> 10:21:31 PM: ❯ Current directory 10:21:31 PM:   /opt/build/repo
> 10:21:31 PM: ​ 10:21:31 PM: ❯ Config file 10:21:31 PM:   No config
> file was defined: using default values. 10:21:31 PM: ​ 10:21:31 PM: ❯
> Context 10:21:31 PM:   production 10:21:31 PM: ​ 10:21:31 PM:
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 10:21:31 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app
> 10:21:31 PM:
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 10:21:31 PM: ​ 10:21:31 PM: $ npm run build 10:21:31 PM: npm ERR! code
> ENOENT 10:21:31 PM: npm ERR! syscall open 10:21:31 PM: npm ERR! path
> /opt/build/repo/package.json 10:21:31 PM: npm ERR! errno -2 10:21:31
> PM: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/opt/build/repo/package.json' 10:21:31 PM: npm ERR! enoent This is
> related to npm not being able to find a file. 10:21:31 PM: npm ERR!
> enoent 10:21:31 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found
> in: 10:21:31 PM: npm ERR!
> /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2021-01-30T06_21_31_988Z-debug.log 10:21:32
> PM: ​ 10:21:32 PM:
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 10:21:32 PM:   "build.command" failed
> 10:21:32 PM:
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 10:21:32 PM: ​ 10:21:32 PM:   Error message 10:21:32 PM:   Command
> failed with exit code 254: npm run build 10:21:32 PM: ​ 10:21:32 PM:
> Error location 10:21:32 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
> 10:21:32 PM:   npm run build 10:21:32 PM: ​ 10:21:32 PM:   Resolved
> config 10:21:32 PM:   build: 10:21:32 PM:     command: npm run build
> 10:21:32 PM:     commandOrigin: ui 10:21:32 PM:     publish:
> /opt/build/repo/build 10:21:32 PM: Caching artifacts 10:21:32 PM:
> Started saving build plugins 10:21:32 PM: Finished saving build
> plugins 10:21:32 PM: Started saving pip cache 10:21:32 PM: Finished
> saving pip cache 10:21:32 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
> 10:21:32 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies 10:21:32 PM:
> Started saving maven dependencies 10:21:32 PM: Finished saving maven
> dependencies 10:21:32 PM: Started saving boot dependencies 10:21:32
> PM: Finished saving boot dependencies 10:21:32 PM: Started saving rust
> rustup cache 10:21:32 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache 10:21:32
> PM: Started saving go dependencies 10:21:32 PM: Finished saving go
> dependencies 10:21:35 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build
> script returned non-zero exit code: 2 10:21:35 PM: Failing build:
> Failed to build site 10:21:35 PM: Failed during stage 'building site':
> Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 10:21:35 PM: Finished
> processing build request in 12.138963808s

Comment: did you find any solution??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try

CI= npm run build

instead of the
-> npm run build

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue go to you're site dashborad on netify.
Then site setting and open Build & deploy tab from general.
click on edit settings in Build setting area.
and change build command to CI= npm run build

[image]